# Type constraints in instance declaration but not class

Tags: haskell

I want to create an instance with a function definition that has type constraints, but I don't want to add the type constraints to the class.

```
class Foo a where
  f :: a b -> b

instance Foo Maybe where
  f = fMaybe

fMaybe :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> a
fMaybe (Just i) = i+i
fMaybe _ = 0
```

How can I specify that this is an instance for `Maybe`s that contain `Nums`?

This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
class Foo a b where
  f :: a b -> b

instance Foo Maybe Int where
  f = fMaybe

fMaybe :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> a
fMaybe (Just i) = i+i
fMaybe _ = 0
```

But I don't want to have to declare instances for each type of `Num`

I tried this:

```
class Foo a where
  f :: a -> b

instance (Num b) => Foo (Maybe b) where
  f = fMaybe

fMaybe :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> a
fMaybe (Just i) = i+i
fMaybe _ = 0
```

but I get an error:

> ```
> Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘b1’
>   ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>       the instance declaration at Test.hs:31:10
>   ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>        the type signature for f :: Maybe b -> b1 at Test.hs:32:3
> Expected type: Maybe b -> b1
>   Actual type: Maybe b1 -> b1
> Relevant bindings include
>   f :: Maybe b -> b1 (bound at Test.hs:32:3)
> In the expression: fMaybe
> In an equation for ‘f’: f = fMaybe
> ```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. `Maybe` is simply not a valid instance of your class as defined.

Comment: The reason that your last example gives an error is that the class says `f :: Foo a => a -> b` so your instance must have `f :: Num b => Maybe b -> c`, that is given anything that is `Maybe b` for some numeric type `b`, you need to be able to produce something of *any* type and the only thing which inhabits any type is bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible without changing either the class or the type.

- The `MultiParamTypeClasses` approach actually doesn't require that you write separate instances for all `Num` types – the following works:

  ```
  class Foo a b where
    f :: a b -> b

  instance (Num b) => Foo Maybe b where
    f = fMaybe
  ```

  Still, I don't think that's a particularly good approach.
- You can use `ConstraintKinds` to allow each instance to optionally constrain the contained type.

  ```
  {-# LANGAUGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}

  import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

  class Foo a where
    type FooCstrt a b :: Constraint
    type FooCstrt a b = () -- default to unconstrained
    f :: FooCstrt a b => a b -> b

  instance Foo Maybe where
    type FooCstrt Maybe b = Num b
    f = fMaybe
  ```
- You can switch to a type that only allows containing `Num` types in the first place.

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

  data NMaybe where
    NJust :: Num b => b -> NMaybe b
    NNothing :: Num b => NMaybe b
  ```

  Then,

  ```
  class Foo a where
    f :: a b -> b

  instance Foo NMaybe where
    f (NJust i) = i+1
    f (NNothing) = 0
  ```

Comment: Why don't you think MPTC is the right approach? On the surface, at least, it looks good to me. Relatively, anyway. I'm not convinced the whole goal is right.

Comment: The MPTC solution you gave is exactly what I was looking for; I didn't realize you could do that. I needed to enable `FlexibleContexts` to get it to work, though. Why do you think this is not a good way to go?

Comment: @bwroga, well, I don't know what you're *actually* doing, but a class that adds one to the contents of a `Maybe` and does somethiing else for other types smells pretty ad hoc.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: The reason I'm doubtful about the MPTC solution is that it makes the `Foo` class quite fundamentally different from the original, namely, it has a different kind `* -> * -> *` instead of `* -> *`. That makes it quite deeply incompatible.